# Browser lags during long process on Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, multithreading, spring-mvc, stream, lag

Given is a Spring MVC-based Webapp that executes received client source code(written in java) and returns it's output.

In the jsp, I have a jquery function that sends client code to the server through:

```
$.post(contextPath('/submit/run'), {
    className: className, // somewhere blah blah
    source: code,
    args: args,
    stdin: stdin
}, function(data) {
    log(data);
});
```

Which is recieved by:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/run", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String run(@RequestParam("className") String className,
                                @RequestParam("source") String source,
                                @RequestParam("args") String args,
                                @RequestParam("stdin") String stdin){
    final CodeRunner runner = ...; // Compiles, Executes..
    return runner.run(); // Then returns output from StdOut
}
```

Everything works fine, yet. The runner can execute code in a defined time, i.e.: kills the thread if exceeds `n` second. However, if the client code executes a code with loop that runs in `<~n sec` such as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) 
    System.out.println("Not so infinite loop.");// runs 0.87 second, but prints a lot
```

**The browser lags, as it seem to be waiting for the response.**

I initially thought that perhaps my way of appending the output to the string builder inside the runner is a loop. So I changed this:

```
String line;
while((line = reader.readline()) != null){
    output.append(line).append("\r\n"); // output = StringBuilder, reader = BufferedReader
}
```

to this, as I've seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string):

```
output.append(IOUtils.toString(proc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

**The browser recovered from the lag faster.**

Obviously, still not enough. If the code is allowed to run for `n=5 seconds`, and it executes in `<n seconds`, the browser will lag for `<n seconds` as well.

**Question:** What approach can I use to circumvent this? I am thinking of partially sending output chunks so that the page receives a response immediately, and rest of the output will follow. If this is a good approach, how do I configure such in jquery and the spring controller?

Or more importantly, is there a better approach?

**P.S.:** I am sure that the appending of the InputStream is the problem, since commenting the line out removes the lag.